# BigTable app profile not showing in cloud logs or Monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable, google-cloud-logging

We created **app profile** and using this app profile while reading. And we are using **hbase-site.xml** for connecting to BigTable.

```
<property>
   <name>google.bigtable.app.profile.id</name>
   <value>read_profile</value>
</property>
```

But we are not seeing profile based graphs/metrics in BigTable **Monitoring**. And neither the Audit read logs in **Cloud Logs** have this info.

What could be issue?

Answer (score 0):

Enabling Metrics:

The Cloud Bigtable HBase client for Java uses the Dropwizard metric to collect and report client-side metrics. Because collecting metrics can add a very small amount of latency (single-digit microseconds) to each request, metrics are not enabled by default.

You can export [Dropwizard metrics](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-metrics) on the client side, which will give you detailed client-side performance metrics, such as end-to-end request latency, that you can track on your own, e.g., via your own [graphite](https://graphiteapp.org/) instance.

Additional Hbase information:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/installing-hbase-shell
- https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/app-profiles